# Mail app unable to verify account name or password

Tags: mac, mail.app, email, ms-office

Lately, I 've been experiencing a problem with my hotmail account when I try to get connected through the `mail.app` on my Mac (I have the latest version of MacOS installed). It cannot get connected and actually this is the error message that pops out.
[image]

I have also tried to delete my hotmail account and re-add it, without any success. Also, I have tried Microsoft Outlook for Mac and I experience the same problem. IMAP settings seem to be correct.

All my other accounts work properly.

P.S. I can get connected to my hotmail account when I use a browser.

Comment: did you enable two-factor authentication for your hotmail account recently? You'll need a special generated app password for osx mail then

Comment: @dennismuys No, I haven't enabled 2 step verification.

Comment: Same problem. Looks like the problem might be on Microsoft's side: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-oapps/cant-connect-outlook-to-any-mail-app/8857c39d-f211-4657-9dbf-f635585b7f83

Comment: try to login on the web... you might got locked. go to setting and verify that outlook definitions are right

Answer (score 1):

I created an outlook.com alias per the link below and it now works  See the link below:

http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/set-up-hotmail-on-mac-os-x-3628423/

I also deleted my account and re-added to switch from pop3 to Imap.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review